# Шейкерная сортировка для списка

Tags: c#, сортировка

> Вывести фамилии учеников в порядке возрастания их роста, используя метод шейкер – сортировки

Создал класс `Student` для описания (возможно ли сделать это с помощь двумерного массива?)

Есть код для массива. Не могу применить алгоритм к списку и вывести фамилии. Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей.

```
namespace Appp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Student
        {
            public string name;
            public double sheight;
 
            public Student(string name, double sHeight)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.sheight = sHeight;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            List<Student> listS = new List<Student>();
            //Добавление учеников
            listS.Add(new Student("Ivanov", 165.1));
            listS.Add(new Student("Petrov", 145.1));
            listS.Add(new Student("Sidorov", 150.3));
 
            // Шейк-сортировка
            static void ShakerSort(int[] listS)
            {
                int left = 0,
                    right = listS.Length - 1,
                    count = 0;
 
                while (left < right)
                {
                    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (listS[i] > listS[i + 1])
                            Swap(listS, i, i + 1);
                    }
                    right--;
 
                    for (int i = right; i > left; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (listS[i - 1] > listS[i])
                            Swap(listS, i - 1, i);
                    }
                    left++;
                }
                static void Swap(int[] listS, int i, int j)
                {
                    int glass = listSt[i];
                    listS[i] = listSt[j];
                    listS[j] = glass;
                }
                static void WriteArray(int[] a)
                {
                    foreach (int i in a)
                        Console.Write("{0}|", i.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему у вас класс `Student` внутри класса `Program`? Не используйте вложенные классы, это плохая практика, за редкими исключениями.

Почему метод `ShakerSort` внутри метода `Main`? Не используйте вложенные методы, это плохая практика, за редкими исключениями. `Swap` и `WriteArray` - то же самое. Не лепите матрёшки там где без них можно обойтись, с ними сложнее работать.

В остальном, достаточно было заменить типы и обращаться к нужному полю при сортировке. Ну переименовал вам немного переменные, уделяйте внимание читаемости кода.

```
class Student
{
    public string name;
    public double height;

    public Student(string name, double height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

        students.Add(new Student("Ivanov", 165.1));
        students.Add(new Student("Petrov", 145.1));
        students.Add(new Student("Sidorov", 150.3));

        StudentShakerSort(students);

        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{student.name} {student.height}");
        }
    }

    static void StudentShakerSort(List<Student> list)
    {
        int left = 0,
            right = list.Count - 1,
            count = 0;

        while (left < right)
        {
            for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
            {
                count++;
                if (list[i].height > list[i + 1].height)
                    Swap(list, i, i + 1);
            }
            right--;

            for (int i = right; i > left; i--)
            {
                count++;
                if (list[i - 1].height > list[i].height)
                    Swap(list, i - 1, i);
            }
            left++;
        }

    }

    static void Swap(List<Student> list, int i, int j)
    {
        Student x = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = x;
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Petrov 145,1
Sidorov 150,3
Ivanov 165,1
```

> возможно ли сделать это с помощью двумерного массива?

Возможно всё, но зачем?

Comment: а можно вам вопрос, почему вы удаляете ответы и комментарии при этом минус еще ставите?

Comment: @cbrngst ответ я удалил, потому что вы посчитали полезным другой ответ, про минусы ничего не знаю.

Comment: в общем я понял как тут рейтинг набивают..

Comment: буду на вас жалобу писать

Comment: @cbrngst пишите, мне незачем ставить минусы. Гораздо веселее будет снять с вас мой плюс, который стоит на вопросе выше. Но я минусы или плюсы не людям ставлю, а тому что они публикуют. Здесь голосуют за контент, а не за людей.

Comment: хорошо поверю, но это странно выглядит